# ggplot's show.legend with named vectors does not work as expected

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, geom-curve

I have several colour arguments with `geom_polygon`, `geom_curve`, and `geom_point` in the same `ggplot`, but I want to have just one of the `colour` arguments shown in the legend...

I have a `mapdata` resultant of a `left_join` of

- the object `globe` (data frame with world country locations):

```
    library(ggplot2)    
    globe <- map_data("world")    
    library(maps)
```

- and a dataset with my variables related to each country in the `globe` dataset

And the plot was initially generated using:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = globe, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), colour = 'black', fill = NA)+
  geom_curve(data = mapdata, aes(x = long.x,    y = lat.x, 
                               xend = long.y, yend = lat.y,
                               size=varA,alpha=0.01,
                               colour="#FFFFFF"),
show.legend=c(size=TRUE,colour=FALSE,alpha=FALSE))+
  geom_point(data=mapdata,aes(x=long.x,y=lat.x,
                                  colour=varB,
                                  size=VarC))+
  coord_equal()
```

- I understand it is possible to use the named logical vectors and I have included `, show.legend=c(size=TRUE, colour=FALSE,alpha=FALSE)` as indicated in the documentation...

But the code returns:
[image: result1]

- Note the "#FFFFFF" related to the colours at `geom_curve` is listed under the same legend for colours at `geom_point`.

(The original legend (full dataset) is):
[image: full legend]

So, `show.legend` with named vectors is not working as expected.

- it clearly works for hiding the legend for `alpha`;
- but not for `colour` in `geom_curve`;
- and the `colour` legend for both `geom_curve` and `geom_point` is shown.

It appears I am missing something here... What I am doing wrong?  Can someone help me, please?

Thanks in advance,

---

A shorter version of the dataset is presented below for reproducibility.

```
mapdata<-structure(list(lat.x = c(42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 
42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 
42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 
42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69, 42.69), long.x = c(23.31, 
23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 
23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 
23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 
23.31, 23.31), capital.x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), VarC = c(31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 
31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 
31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 
31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 
31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 
31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 
31656.6425968, 31656.6425968, 31656.6425968), lat.y = c(52.52, 
52.52, 52.52, 52.52, 39.93, 39.93, 41.72, 33.72, 14.72, 50.43, 
34.02, -1.29, NA, 14.63, 33.88, 36.84, 40.17, 44.83, 31.78, 40.39, 
29.38, NA, 48.16, 53.33, 45.8, 50.83, 59.44, 40.42, 40.39, 14.63
), long.y = c(13.38, 13.38, 13.38, 13.38, 32.85, 32.85, 44.79, 
73.06, -17.48, 30.52, -6.84, 36.82, NA, -90.55, 35.5, 10.22, 
44.52, 20.5, 35.22, 49.86, 47.99, NA, 17.13, -6.25, 15.97, 4.33, 
24.74, -3.71, 49.86, -90.55), varA = c(2.6657688088456, 2.6657688088456, 
2.6657688088456, 2.6657688088456, 4.44265125649032, 4.44265125649032, 
5.43372200355424, 9.06508335931904, 6.87212810133899, 6.04500531403601, 
6.73696695800186, 6.14846829591765, 6.89365635460264, 3.95124371858143, 
5.04985600724954, 2.39789527279837, 4.89034912822175, 2.07944154167984, 
5.68697535633982, 5.78074351579233, 2.39789527279837, 7.87473912517181, 
4.969813299576, 2.89037175789616, 3.25809653802148, 9.3461815948876, 
0.693147180559945, 0.693147180559945, 5.78074351579233, 3.95124371858143
), varB = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("(-1e-05,4.82e+04]", "(4.82e+04,8.22e+05]", 
"(8.22e+05,2.28e+06]", "(2.28e+06,5.63e+06]", "(5.63e+06,1.69e+07]", 
"(1.69e+07,6.91e+07]", "(6.91e+07,1.14e+08]"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

---

The documentation describing the `show.legend` parameter (inside geom_curve or geom_segment) is available [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html).

Comment: Can you link to the docs that you're referring to? I've always done this stuff with `guides()` before - is a different method now recommended?

Comment: It seems to be a misplacement of a «)». Only arguments specifying variables need to be inside `aes()`, so you can move the closing parenthasis to before `alpha=0.01, colour="#FFFFFF"`.

Comment: @jpiversen,thank you for your message. I was not aware that aes() components can be moved in/out according to being variable-related or not... I have included them inside parenthesis because both `alpha` and `colour` can have variable specified... Closing the parenthesis before `alpha=0.01, colour="#FFFFFF"` makes indeed the "#FFFFFF" disappear... But also makes the curves from `geom_curve` disappear...

Comment: This is because you use `alpha = 0.01`, which makes the curves almost invisible. I will upload an answer (instead of a comment) shortly, please upvote and mark as the solution it if it solves your issue :)

Comment: @SamR, thank you for your message. I will add the documentation. The `guides()` does not apply here because there are over one 'colour' parameter... so adding `+guides(colour='none')` would make all legends for colour (including those from `geom_point`) be hidden... or do we have ways to specify which of colour legends to hide and which to show using `guides()`?

Comment: @jpiversen, yea, that's true... I changed to alpha=1 and was able to see the curves... but the curve colour changed... it was something like pink before, and now is white... so maybe the colour was ignored before, and ggplot2's default is red or something like it... understood... thanks a lot!

Comment: That's correct. You specified `colour = "#FFFFFF"`, which is completely white. But since you included this in `aes()`, R treated it as a variable with a single value, and gave it a default color. You can change `"#FFFFFF"` to any colour you like when it specified outside `aes()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that "colour" shows up in the legend is because it is included in the `aes()` function.

The `aes()` function describes how variables in the  `data` should be mapped to the plot. Arguments not found as variables in your `data` (such as `alpha` and `colour` in this case) should be put outside the `aes()` function.

Using your data, I would change the code as such (see comments for what I've changed):

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(
    data = globe,
    aes(
      x = long, 
      y = lat, 
      group = group
    ), 
    colour = "black", 
    fill = NA
  ) +
  geom_curve(
    data = mapdata, 
    aes(
      x = long.x, 
      y = lat.x,
      xend = long.y, 
      yend = lat.y,
      size = varA
    ), # I have moved this paranthesis so alpha annd colour is outside aes()
    alpha = 0.5, # I have increased this value, to make the lines visible
    colour = "blue", # I also changed this, to make the lines blue instead of white
    show.legend = c(size = TRUE, colour = FALSE, alpha = FALSE)
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = mapdata, 
    aes(
      x = long.x, 
      y = lat.x,
      colour = varB,
      size = VarC
    )
  ) +
  coord_equal()
```

The result:

[image]